# How to align button on middle of the image in the carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Actually I am trying to make a carousel in which there will be button in the middle of the image but could not...please help...i am posting the photo of that website which i am trying to make and also posting [my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlWiA.png)

[image: image of website]

Comment: Can you show some code so it is easy to help

Comment: You can use bootstrap for this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/

Comment: i have been bootstrap carousel.But instead of using caption....i want to use button on it..which is not happening..

Comment: Please post your code in your question as it will allow us to try it on our end and provide an answer with it. (instead of a screenshot that could be a dead link in the future)

Comment: Though the answer is solved....Next time I will make sure to post my code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have an image as your background, style it how you want with width and height. And then you want to have a text or content container which will be `position: absolute;`, this will cause your text to overlay the image. From there set `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; width: 100%; height: 100%;` and this will cause your text to center on the image.

Make sure this is contained in a container with `position: relative` so your absolute positioned element goes to the bounds of the container and not the page.

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image-class"/>
  <div class="text-container">
    your text elements here
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.image-class {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

That should get you close to what you're looking for. I've included a codepen with a quick example: https://codepen.io/sean-mooney/pen/ZEGNVrw

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

The above example demonstrates how to align the text over an image, however in a carousel this can be a little different. The concept remains the same but implementation can be tricky. I've included another codepen demonstrating how to use that example within a carousel:

https://codepen.io/sean-mooney/pen/jOPogrY

Comment: Sorry but it is not happening

Comment: @card98 whoops you're 100% right, I gave you bad code. I mixed up how to do it, the text content is supposed to be positioned absolute, not the image. That's my fault sorry about that. I've updated the answer and included a codepen so you can see how I did it.

Comment: As per your example I have done the image with the button on middle of it. Now I want to include that image with the middle-aligned button on  bootstrap carousel.Kindly please help me.

Comment: @card98 I've updated the answer to include another codepen, this one uses the bootstrap carousel and the idea for centering the text/button over an image that I mentioned earlier. Hope that helps!